# Springbooot entities share the same JPA entity name: which is not allowed

Tags: spring-boot, entity

I got this error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: The [com.KRON.ReportPortal.Model.RPT_BILANCA.Dohvati_BilancaPoOperatorima2] and [com.KRON.ReportPortal.Model.RPT_REPORT_PORTAL.Dohvati_BilancaPoOperatorima2] ****entities share the same JPA entity name: [Dohvati_BilancaPoOperatorima2] which is not allowed!****

when I try to deploye springboot application.

But I dont have model **Dohvati_BilancaPoOperatorima2** in my project.
[Springboot Model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m886d.png)

Any help please?

Comment: It looks like the names of entities has been trimmed to maximum length of 29 characters. Check your settings.

Comment: @Mar-Z Thank you for your replay. I changed the names of entities and checked setting, but I got the same error. Friend of mine pulled same project and he don't have that error.

Comment: what is your hibernate version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting project and cloning it again.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any dependencies in your project that define an entity with the same name. You can try excluding those dependencies from your project or renaming your entity to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I changed the names and checked if any dependencies define name of entities. But with no luck I still got a error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the error by manually deleting some generated directories in my Spring project under IntelliJ. I deleted the `build` directory, `.gradle` directory, and `out` directory. After that, I rebuilt the project and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened when I upgraded hibernate from version 5.2.4 to version 5.6.10. While researching the cause of the problem, I found out that it was version bound. Although the entity class names were the same in the previous version, I distinguished them from the table names in the base using the @Table annotation. Example:
@Table(name="adm_menu",schema="admin")
@Table(name="aas_menu",schema="aas")
However, this use was not possible in the new version

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I built my project on a previous commit. After switching back to the current commit, which had the same class but the package was renamed, I got this error. Building the project again resolved it.

Comment: This means that there were class files built in the previous commit and they weren't cleaned whereas in the current commit you probably added another bean or entity and caused naming clash. But the context of VCS commits is irrelevant to the question, hence the answer is low quality.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the JPA entity name. ie.

 **@Entity(name="STUDENT_API_APP")**

@Table(name="STUDENT")

@Data

public class Student {

// fields

}